# Derivative of power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$$ be a power series mapping reals to reals, with radius of convergence $R$. Suppose $f'(x_0)$ exists in $[-R,R]$ (take the one-sided limit if $x_0 = R$ or $x_0 = -R$). Then is it always true that
$$f'(x_0) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1}?$$

This clearly holds if $x_0 \in (-R,R)$. But what about $x_0 = R$?

**EDIT:** Even though I have accepted the answer, I'm wondering if there still exists a counterexample if $a_k$ is restricted to the nonnegative reals for all $k$. It would be very helpful if someone can answer that.

Comment: Does the series for $f$ converges at both endpoints?

Comment: Yes. The derivative also exists at the endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: consider
$$ f(x) = \log{(1+x^2)}. $$
Then
$$ f(x) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^k}{k}, $$
which is an alternating series with decreasing terms for $-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, so it converges on $[-1,1]$. It does not converge outside this interval by applying the ratio test. Then
$$ f'(x) = \frac{2x}{1+x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2x(-x^2)^k $$
for $x \in (-1,1)$, and $f'(1)=1$, but the right-hand side evaluated at $x=1$ would be
$$ 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k, $$
which is not Cauchy and so does not converge.

Comment: This is nice! But do you have an example where the power series is given by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$? Your example uses $(-x^2)^k$ instead.

Comment: One form can be massaged into the other by appropriate definition of the coefficients: taking $a_{2k} = (-1)^{k+1}/(k)$, and $a_{2k+1}=0$ as the odd ones gives the same series.

Comment: Yes, that is very true, thanks! I'm wondering, what if we restrict the coefficients $a_k \geq 0$ for all $k$, then would there still be a counterexample? The reason I'm doing this is I'm trying to figure out the correct answer for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473735/factorial-moment-and-derivative-of-probability-generating-function). Anyhow, I have accepted your answer!